# How can I synchronize execution of URLSession on SWIFT 5?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, urlsession

I make an url communication by URLSession.

```
func performRequest(with urlString: String, model: stateDataModel) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let safeData = data {
                    DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                        self.parseHTML(htmlString: safeData, model: model)
                    }
                } else if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithCar(error: error!)
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

AS "data" I get html text. I convert that to string, cut needing info and set to class. Object of this class I create in viewController and send as parameter to performRequest.

I need to work witn that new data in viewController, but program set received data to class after that (old) data was used in view controller.
Example of viewController function:

```
    @IBAction func activatePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let req = "app"
        carManager.fetchCar(request: req, model: stateData)
        
        print("State data:" + stateData.getData())
        
        let pressedButton : UIButton = sender as! UIButton
        pressedButton.isHidden = true;
        
        stateLabel.text = stateData.getData()
        stateLabel.isHidden = false
    }
```

How can I fix this situation?

Comment: Your URLSession is handled as asynchronous call that's why "fetchCar" before updating your model, the next line gets executed which already has old data and completes the IBAction func with old data.

Comment: if the middle code is present it would be helpful. However have a look on `semaphore` or `try await` concepts and implement whichever fits well in your design.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As always, it’s enough just ask a question to solve the problem yourself. I just added a protocol, that runs asynchronously, and call that from url task :)